# Is there a U.K. prepaid card having SWIFT, BIC, or IBAN codes, for money transfer?

Tags: credit-card, united-kingdom, banking, money-transfer

I'm located in the U.K.  Does anyone know if pre-paid cards here, such as Visa prepaid cards, have a SWIFT or BIC or IBAN code, because they are not really a current account?

For example, for the Virgin money prepaid card, do you think is it possible have SWIFT or BIC code, to transfer money from the card to a bank, or from a bank to the card?

Answer (score 4):

I contacted Virgin Money to ask if the [prepaid card](http://uk.virginmoney.com/virgin/prepaid-card/) you mentioned offers a Swift/BIC code, and they gave me this response:

> We do not have a Swift or BIC number for the Virgin Prepaid Card. You are unable to transfer funds from the Prepaid Card to another bank but you can set up a bank transfer to the Prepaid Card.
>
> Once you receive your card you can log onto your online account and you will have a form you can print off. On the form you will have an account number, sort code and a unique reference number for your bank to set up the transfer.

This may work for your purposes, or it may not. If you want more information about that specific card, your best bet is to [contact them](http://uk.virginmoney.com/virgin/prepaid-card/contact.jsp) and ask any other specific questions you have. The same strategy should work for any prepaid card company. Just call or email them, describe your situation, and ask if their card will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Every single prepaid card I thinks works in different way. For example with Vergin prepaid visa card it is impossible set up payment by direct debits, but with clear cash yes http://www.clearcash.co.uk/faq/
Do you think clear cash has switch or Swift/BIC code?
Clear cash works with APS Financial Limited (AFL), who are they? Is a Bank or a financial institute?
In theory they should not have Swift/BIC code, but have more services than Virgin.
Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: @george I don't know about that specific company; I suggest you [contact Clearcash](http://www.clearcash.co.uk/contact/) about their cards directly, since they'll be able to provide more specific information than I can.